# Commit multiple tables at once in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have below method which saves multiple tables. currently commit is happening separately  for two tables. it means when i debug i can see commit happens seperatly for employeeDetails and companyDetails table

```
public void saveDB()
{
   employeeDetailsRepo.save(employee);
   companyDetailsRepo.save(companyDetails);

}
```

What i am trying to do is commit should happens only once. e.g when i debug i don't want 1st table data committed and then next table. I want is once control coming out from this method we should se data saved  in both the tables simultaneously. to do this I tried @Transcational on my saveDB method annotation along with @EnableTransactionManagement on main class of springBoot but it is not working. also tried below  but not working

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {
            Exception.class }, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)

    public void saveDB()
    {
       employeeDetailsRepo.save(employee);
       companyDetailsRepo.save(companyDetails);
    
    }
```

Also below property added in config flag

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =false
```

Comment: Just curious what is the negative side effect you are trying to avoid with the "double" commit?

Comment: Let's say if 1st table commit successful and during 2nd table commit if any issue occured it means 2nd table commit is not successful. Then in this case as it is a complete transaction I want either both tables successful or not, I don't want only  1st table commited @Hermann Steidal

Comment: But that's what a plain ole `@Transacational` does for you. I think you might be overthinking it. Everything wrapped in the transaction won't get flushed to the db unless the entire transaction is successful. You can try an experiment, throw a RuntimeException in between the two saves and see if table #1 actually gets written to. Then move that throw after the second save and run it again, see if any of the tables get written to. When you check, check the actual DB for changes.

Comment: exactly my use case.. Transactional does not work. @HermannSteidel.. the individual tables get committed even with Transactional annotation