# @Transactional annotation on save/saveAll vs @Transactional annotation on custom method which calls saveAll

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

[Commit multiple tables at once in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906233/commit-multiple-tables-at-once-in-spring-boot) did not help

I am new to Spring (Boot) Data JPA. I am trying to insert data into 2 different tables using *repo1.saveAll* and *repo2.saveAll* from within a method that has the transactional annotation.

```
@Autowired
Table1Repo repo1; //corresponding to Table1; interface extending JPA's CRUDRepository
@Autowired
Table2Repo repo2; //corresponding to Table2; interface extending JPA's CRUDRepository

@Transactional
void saveMyData(List<Table1Entity> dataForTable1,List<Table2Entity> dataForTable2){
//i want the commit to happen AFTER both statements have been completed 
repo1.saveAll(dataForTable1)
repo2.saveAll(dataForTable2)
}
```

I expect the data to be committed to both the tables together or nothing with the *@Transactional* annotation.

But when I check the tables I find that the after *saveAll* to **table1** is completed, the data becomes available in **table1** in the Database *(as checked from the SQL Developer studio)* and then the *saveAll* to **table2** proceeds. This violates the atomicity of a transaction. I was expecting *@Transactional* annotation to take care of this.

When I dug in, I found out that the *save/saveAll/delete/deleteAll* etc. methods of the *SimpleJPARepository* are also already annotated with *@Transactional* annotation. Is that the reason why the *@Transactional* annotation that I have used for my method **gets ignored** and the data gets committed at each *saveAll* call made from within my method thanks to the *saveAll* method's *@Transactional* annotation meaning that each *saveAll* call is executed within its own transaction. Does it mean using *@Transactional* on a custom method like *saveMyData* has no meaning when calling *saveAll* method on the repo from within that method?

Comment: The repository methods marked as `@Transactional` should reuse the existing transaction by default instead of opening a new one.

Comment: But that's not happening..i can see data in table1 even before saveAll for table2 is complete..which means a commit for table1 has already happened..therefore precisely the question

Comment: From which class is the `saveMyData` method called?

Comment: it was from within the class.. i called it from a diferent class and it started working..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction annotation is executed as a single work unit from the method started and guarantees All or Nothing, i.e. atomicity. In other words, even if @Transactional is attached to a method, it is not separated into a separate transaction unless the requires_new option is attached. The suspected problem is when a method annotated with @Transactional is called from a method in an inner class that is not annotated with @Transactional. In that case, @Transactional will not work as expected because the spring bean is acting as a proxy.