# Is calling method of EntityManager in a container-managed transaction context inside Servlet thread-safe?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager, jta

There is the following code snippet inside a *servlet*

```
@PeristenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
           throws ServletException,
                  IOException {
    runTransaction();
}
@Transactional
public void runTransaction() {
   entityManager.merge(entityA);
   entityManager.remove(entityC);
}
```

`entityManager` methods are invoked inside container-managed transaction bounday => **Question: is there any problem when calling the `runTransaction()` inside the `doPost` method? esp. is calling of `runTransaction()` thread-safe? If this approach is problematic, how to resolve?**

Comment: This link maybe help you about for internal method call problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77532694/transactional-annotation-on-save-saveall-vs-transactional-annotation-on-custom/77534786#77534786

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it may be thread-safe (cause it is request dependent), but it certainly is not transactional. `@Transactional` annotation activates transactions boundaries only when there is a "business method invocation" as defined by item [2.6.2 of CDI spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0#biz_method). In your case, servlet's doPost is calling a method inside its own class, so it will not be intercepted.

To be able to start the transaction, you should move the database code (entitymanager injection and runTransaction method) to another CDI bean (you may choose a `@RequestScoped` to be thread-safe) and call that bean from your servlet. So:

```
@RequestScoped
public class DataManager {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void runTransaction(...) {
        // Do your thing here
    }
}

@WebServlet("/save")
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private DataManager dataManager;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // Gather data to be saved
        dataManager.runTransaction(/*arguments*/); // transaction will be started just before this method is actually called and will end before returning the result to this method
        // return response using resp
    }
}
```

As `dataManager` is a `@RequestScoped` CDI proxy, each time a call is made to it, the proper request context bean will be called, making it request dependent and thread-safe. Note that data sharing between beans may interfere the thread-safiness of the execution, so choose what you pass to `runTransaction` method wisely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, but is `@PersistenceContext` annotation thread-safe? In addition to the thread-safety question, doesn't instantiating a new `EntityManager` instance per request have performance penalty? And in the given code, the injected `EntityManager` through `@PersistenceContext` is not closed at the end of the request

Comment: On the thread-safeness of `@PersistenceContext`, I'll direct you to the [7.6 chapter of Jakarta Persistence spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0#a11791), making clear that it is thread-safe, but prone to optimistic exceptions, and adding that the performance impact is negligible. On the close question, the life cycle commands that (and it will close only after the hole transaction finishes). You always can create `EntityManager`'s `@RequestScoped @Producer` and it will be shared between all the CDI beans in your request.